# Disable faint of display Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, brightness

I want to know there is exist some way to disable faint of display brightness when I don't connected to energy network(I use notebook).

I have already set on both pages Brightness and Supply to do nothing when energy gets disconnected, but it still get low brightness after few second.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting it in `Control Center` and then `Power Management Preferences`? You should go to `On Battery Power` and configure it as you like.

Comment: I already do this, and still have the problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I probably can't help you then. But try `sudo xset s 1 1` or `sudo xset dpms force off`.

Comment: Try only `sudo xset dpms force off`. I made a mistake, sorry.

Comment: If that doesn't help, another solution is to run it indefinitely. `while :; do sudo xset dmps force off; done`. You can interrupt it by holding `ctrl+c`. It is a stupid solution, but it is working. And you don't have to look what is wrong.